# execve with path search?

Tags: c, exec, execve

I want to execute a program from my code, and supply it with environment variables and arguments. AFAICT, `execve` is the right choice.

But, `execve` receives a `path` argument, not a `filename`, meaning it expects the first argument to be a path to the executable.

I know I can parse `$PATH` myself to find the path, but really, is there no other choice? Has no one else implemented it somewhere for me to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some systems may provide `execvpe()`.  A Google search for 'execvpe' shows a variety of options, including at least one implementation (considerably more complex than what follows, but it includes most of `execvp()` in its own code).

For those that do not, you can provide it for yourself:

```
int execvpe(const char *program, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    char **saved = environ;
    int rc;
    environ = envp;
    rc = execvp(program, argv);
    environ = saved;
    return rc;
}
```

You probably could survive without `rc` (just forcibly returning -1) since `execvp()` only ever returns `-1` (and it only ever returns on an error).

You probably do not even have to worry about thread safety in this code.  The normal scenario where it is used will be in a child process just after a `fork()`, and at that point, there is only one thread in the process.  If you think you may use it when there are multiple threads around, then you need to think rather carefully about whether it is safe to modify the global environment even briefly.  Clearly, if the `execvp()` succeeds, there won't be a problem (all the threads will be abruptly terminated).  If the `execvp()` fails, then maybe one of the other threads would see the modified environment and might make bad decisions based on that.  In which case, you would need to protect the environment appropriately (and that probably involves (mutual exclusion) locking in `getenv()`, `setenv()` and `putenv()` as well as in `execvpe()`).

(The implementation of `execvpe()` that I found avoids the thread-safety issues by implementing `execvp()` logic and then using `execve()` to execute the program.)

Normally, if `execvpe()` returns, the process will exit, so very often reinstating the environment is not going to affect the program.  However, it is better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Warning: the code has not formally been tested - use with appropriate caution.