# Fork and execve segmentation fault

Tags: c, fork, execve

My program should use fork and exec system calls. The exec should change the child process such that it takes another command as an argument and executes
that command. For example, to display the message of the day:

```
 ./myexec cat /etc/motd
```

This is my current code

```
extern char **environ;      /* environment info */
main(int argc, char **argv) {
     /* argc -- number of arguments */
     /* argv -- an array of strings */

    char *argvNew[argc + 1];
    int pid;

    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++){
        argvNew[i] = argv[i];
    }
    argvNew[argc + 1] = NULL;
    printf("After For: %s\n",argvNew[0]);
    printf("After For: %s\n",argvNew[1]);
    printf("After For: %s\n",argvNew[2]);
    printf("After For: %s\n",argvNew[3]);


    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork error%sstrerror\n", strerror(errno));

        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        /* child process */
        if (execve(argvNew[0], argvNew, environ) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Execve error%d %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        /* parent */
    wait(0);        /* wait for the child to finish */
    }

}
```

After running `./myexecv cat etc/motd` nothing happens; just the print statements. Any advice going forward?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to copy the argument list. Unless there's a formal mandate to use `execve()` rather than just `execv()`, use that. Your whole code should be just: `execv(argv[1], &argv[1]);` — no fork, no copy, no wait, nothing else. The only marginal 'benefit' of the fork/exec/wait regime in the original code is that the return code from the parent is always 0 regardless of whether the executed command succeeds or not (assuming you use a C99 or better compiler, so falling off the end of main is equivalent to `return 0`, but then `main` should have an explicit `int` return type).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However nothing happens still after write a command. The output i get is                               @ubuntu:~/Documents$ ./myfork ls -l
After For: ls
After For: -l
After For: (null)
After For: (null)
Execve error2 No such file or directory

Comment: Ah...Using `execv()` or `execve()`, you have to specify the absolute name of the executable (or the name relative to the current directory).  Try: `./myexec /bin/cat /etc/motd` (or maybe `./myexec /usr/bin/cat /etc/motd` if that's where `cat` is).   That should work.  To do the shell-like PATH-based search for `cat`, use `execvp()` — or, if you can find the code and you really want to, [`execvpe()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789750), but since you don't alter the environment, there's really no point in using the environment-setting variants.

Comment: I ended up using `#include <unistd.h>`
 and
`int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    return 1;
}` —— When compiled and run (`./myexec cat /etc/motd`) I got the error message `cat: /etc/motd: No such file or directory` which is accurate on my machine; there is no `/etc/motd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++){
            argvNew[i] = argv[i];
    }
    argvNew[argc+1] = NULL;
```

On it's face value, the NULL assignment is wrong, and will result in undefined behavior because `argvNew` is declared as

```
    char *argvNew[argc + 1];
```

So the array contains values `argvNew[0]` through `argvNew[argc]`, and `argvNew[argc+1]=NULL;` runs off past the end of the array, that results in undefined behavior. This should obviously be

```
    argvNew[argc] = NULL;
```

But even that would also be wrong, because:

```
 execve(argvNew[0], argvNew, environ);
```

`argvNew[0]` is copied from `argv[0]`, which is the name of this program being executed. This is going to fork and run the same program, in the child process.

You will end up forkbombing yourself. If this is a shared server, you will make the system administrator very very mad.

You need to remove `argv[0]` from the equation, and copy over only `argv[1]`, and on. The correct loop, and copy, is:

```
    int pid;
    char *argvNew[argc];

    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
            argvNew[i-1] = argv[i];
    }
    argvNew[argc-1] = NULL;
```

Comment: What's the benefit of the copying at all?  Why not just `execve(argv[1], &argv[1], environ);` or `execv(argv[1], &argv[1]);`?

Comment: There is no benefit. But this is just a [mcve], and the OP's actual code could be doing additional manipulation on the `argv`.

Answer (score 1):

The calling parameters of [`execve()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) require the first parameter to be the filename to execute.  Unfortunately you pass it `argvNew[0]` which is the same value as `argv[0]`.  This means that you call and call again your own program and never the script. You need to shift the parameters by one:

```
...
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    argvNew[i-1] = argv[i];
}
argvNew[argc-1] = NULL;
...
```

Comment: What's the benefit of the copying at all?  Why not just `execve(argv[1], &argv[1], environ);` or `execv(argv[1], &argv[1]);`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Excellent suggestion !!  I've kept the copy because I supposed that OP has simplified the case. I imagine that in reality he'd add/change/remove some parameters; otherwise, what would be the value added by this program ?